Для чего нужны пространства имен XML и чем они отличаются от XSD схем?
Также хотелось бы узнать для чего служат атрибуты XSD-схемы:
xmlns:xs
xmlns
targetNamespace

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/index.htm

Они ортогональны друг другу. Пространство имён - это как фамилия у человека. Схемы - это набор правил. Как, например, правила дорожного движения. Или курить можно только с 18 лет. И т. д. / xmlns: - это не атрибут, это именно указание неймспейса. Ещё раз: указание неймспейса не является атрибутом.
